# Open Data ads on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Let's create ads to make Open Data more widely known!

Propose your designs below, and also post them on the target networks.

Also, please upvote the ads where they are posted: Only ads with more than 6 votes get displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created these:
[image: Open Data StackExchange] [image: Need datasets? Request anything at Open Data]

Please upvote at:

- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3892/1013)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2379/1437)
- [Academics](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1734/307)

Thanks! And feel free to create more :-)

Comment: Thanks for your initiative! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Community Ads at the GIS Stack Exchange are open for voting at the moment, and the one created there by @NicolasRaoul as a result of this question gets re-posted by me each year.

I think it is helpful to both the Open Data and GIS Stack Exchanges to have [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5289/115) to https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/community-ads-for-2021 upvoted.

Also, if anyone from Open Data would like to give the ad a fresh new look they should feel free to edit the existing answer there to do so.

Comment: Thanks! Please also upvote at https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6163/1437 and https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4944/307 :-)